# Arbitrary long integers in Delphi - NX library?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, freepascal, arbitrary-precision

just looking for some implementation of arbitrary large integer numbers with some basic arithmetic (add, mul, div at least) for Delphi.

All solutions I did already found are either painfully slow(FGInt, BigInt, MyBigInt, UBigInts), i386 CPU specific (sdpbigInt) or implemented in C (MPIR/GMP).
So far the best results got with Delphi GMP wrappers for MPIR, but I'd prefer pure Delphi/Asm library (MPIR requires C compiler installed and knowledge of C if would like to study algorithms or do some tweaks).

I've read positive comments about NX multiprecision library written by Marcel Martin, but unfortunately it's no more available to download from the official site at http://www.ellipsa.eu . As code was distributed as freeware including sources, I do not find a problem to get it from other site. Can anybody throw in some alternate download link, please ?

Thanks in an advance.

Comment: "MPIR requires C compiler installed". Presumably just on the dev machine. My instincts suggest that a C lib may be the best compromise, especially since you seem to have severe performance constraints.

Comment: Sure, but frequent rebuild of the library is to be expected - tweaking & testing, updates to newer/fixed versions etc. I can live with this but I'd really like to try the NX library.

Comment: Nobody says you have to move to newer versions. This code is already blazingly fast. It's not going to get any better. I've had good experiences linking compiled C code statically which aids deployment.

Comment: Don't go for anything with inline assembler or it will block you moving to 64 bit Delphi!

Comment: Well, the same goes for external libraries. They might hold you back going to 64-bit too if they are not available in 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specifically ask for a free alternative: StreamSec Tools 4.0. It contains hand optimized assembler for both x86 and x64 and comes with source.